# How to close the new page opened by a HTML anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django-templates

So I am working on a Django template where there are thumbnails on the page that are included within the anchor tags, and when the user clicks on those thumbnails, it opens a new page based upon the href value.
Now if I want to go back to the main page, I need to press the back button.

I wanted to know if is it possible to put a close button on the new page so that the user is taken back to the main page.

Code below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        {% for rest in getMenuImage %}
            <div style="display: inline-block;">
                <a href="{{ rest.image.url }}"><img src="{{ rest.thumbnail.url }}" class="img-responsive" style="padding-right: 10px;border-radius: 5px;"></a>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using `window.history.back();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can close current window and go back to previous by if you opened it new tab:

```
     $(".back").click(function(){
            var url = "page url you want to go back";//back page url
            var objWindow = window.open(url, "_self");
            objWindow.close();
     })
```

One more option to go back is :

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">Back</a>
```

Comment: @Saurabh_Jhingan if answer is working for you may accept it to help others

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript function: `window.history.back();` in a button in the new page.
Here is an example.

```html
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```